# INDEX + MATCH functionality in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i believe there have been other posts with similar titles, but i could not find one which looked like my example

essentially, i am looking to fill in one dataframe based on "looking up" values from another dataframe. both have indexes of dates (datetimeindex) - one is sparse (lookup_df) and one is full (target_df)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

target_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[2]*365, index=pd.date_range('20170101', '20171231'), columns=['value'])

lookup_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[7,4,-5,10,2], index=pd.to_datetime(['20170101', '20170401', '20170701', '20171001','20180101']), columns=['value'])
```

what i would like to obtain is a dataframe of the same size/shape as target_df where the items in the "value" column come from the lookup_df - so matching dates will use the exact value from lookup_df and dates in between will use the earlier matched value.

in excel, this would be accomplished via the INDEX + MATCH functions, but i am not able to achieve this using some of the suggested pandas methods such as .merge()

Answer (score 0):

#### `combine_first`

```
df = lookup_df.combine_first(target_df)

df.loc[lookup_df.index]   # see the changes to `target_df`

            value
2017-01-01    7.0
2017-04-01    4.0
2017-07-01   -5.0
2017-10-01   10.0
2018-01-01    2.0
```

---

#### `Index.intersection` + `loc`

```
idx = lookup_df.index.intersection(target_df.index)
target_df.loc[idx, 'value'] = lookup_df.loc[idx, 'value']
```

This updates `target_df` in place, rather than create a new output `df`.